# Rsync files to a server while changing their ownership without root access

Tags: debian, permissions, rsync

I'm trying to allow users to rsync directories to a remote server, while changing the user and group of the uploaded files/directories to `nobody:nogroup`.

Each user has SSH access to the server via their own username. The users are already members of the group `nogroup` on the  remote server. This has allowed me to change the group of files, but not the user.

I would prefer not to allow users to SSH as root.

I can't figure out how set up permissions on the remote server so that files can be 'given over to' user `nobody`.

Here's the command I'm trying to get working:

`rsync -av --owner=nobody --group=nogroup testdir 123.123.123.123:/mnt/storage/`

Answer (score 0):

From [rsync man page](https://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html):

> **-o, --owner** This option causes rsync to set the owner of the destination file to be the same as the source file, but *only if the receiving rsync is being run as the super-user* (see also the --super and --fake-super options). Without this option, the owner of new and/or transferred files are set to the invoking user on the receiving side.

As your users are **not** superusers on the destination server, they can not change owner permission. This is true for `--owner` as well `--usermap` and `--chown` (just check the relative options in the man page). You can try the `--fake-super` option for a possible workaround.

That said, is often a very good idea to *preserve* the original user/group when copying/backing up files via `rsync`.